# How to display corresponding elements of the active data- category?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two filters , "Bidder" and "Seller". "Bidder" is the active filter.

It is working fine when I clicked on the filters, it is showing their corresponding elements.

The only problem is when the page loads, it is displaying the elements of both the "Bidder" and "Seller" filter. However, I want it to display the corresponding elements of my active filter only when the page loads.

I have tried to use display: none; to hide it but it does not work.

```js
let indicator = document.querySelector('.indicator').children;
let main = document.querySelector('.info').children;

for (let i = 0; i < indicator.length; i++) {
  indicator[i].onclick = function() {
    for (let x = 0; x < indicator.length; x++) {
      indicator[x].classList.remove('active');
    }
    this.classList.add('active');
    const displayItems = this.getAttribute('data-filter');
    for (let z = 0; z < main.length; z++) {
      main[z].style.transform = 'scale(0)';
      setTimeout(() => {
        main[z].style.display = 'none';
      }, 0);

      if ((main[z].getAttribute('data-category') == displayItems)) {
        main[z].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
        setTimeout(() => {
          main[z].style.display = 'block';
        }, 0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="indicator">
  <li data-filter="bidder" class="active">Bidder</a>
  </li>
  <li data-filter="seller">Seller</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class=" info">
  <li data-category="bidder"><a>abc</a></li>
  <li data-category="seller"><a>efg</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your HTML is invalid. I'd plug it into [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/) and make sure to open and close all of those tags.

Secondly, `.style = ...` is often an antipattern, as it seems to be here. Hardcoding CSS into JS is as difficult to maintain as hardcoding JS (or CSS) into HTML. Prefer creating CSS classes, then adding and removing them with `.toggle` and `.classList`. Ideally, classes are the declarative lingua franca/glue between the three worlds of structure, behavior and style.

You can indeed use `display: none` to hide things as you mention, but I don't see any CSS code provided and your JS only runs on click, so there's nothing that would affect visibility on load.

There are at least two options: you can add these visibility classes statically to the HTML or you can assign them from JS after the DOM loads. Which is "better" depends on your use case.

Absent any other contextual information, I'd suggest adding the classes to the static HTML. If you handle it in JS and display the static HTML by default, your user might see the not-yet-hidden elements momentarily then disappear once the JS runs.

As a consequence, if you do use JS, you'd probably want to hide the whole wrapper by default and only show it to the user after your JS has properly assigned the necessary visibility classes using a loop and `classList.add()`.

If you're going that far, you might even generate all of the elements with the correct visibility properties dynamically with JS, depending on where your data is coming from.

Here's a suggestion that shows the usage of classes in HTML that can be added/removed by JS, and have the necessary CSS styling to hide/show by default.

```js
const indicatorEls =
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".indicator li")]
;
const infoEls = [...document.querySelectorAll(".info li")];

for (const el of indicatorEls) {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (const el of indicatorEls) {
      el.classList.remove("active");
    }

    el.classList.add("active");
    const filterTarget = el.getAttribute("data-filter");

    for (const el of infoEls) {
      el.classList.remove("info-item-active");

      if (el.getAttribute("data-category") === filterTarget) {
        el.classList.add("info-item-active");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.info-item {
  display: none;
}
.info-item-active {
  display: block;
}
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="indicator">
  <li data-filter="bidder" class="active">Bidder</li>
  <li data-filter="seller">Seller</li>
</ul>
<ul class="info">
  <li
    data-category="bidder"
    class="info-item info-item-active"
  >
    a
  </li>
  <li data-category="seller" class="info-item">
    b
  </li>
  <li data-category="seller" class="info-item">
    c
  </li>
  <li
    data-category="bidder"
    class="info-item info-item-active"
  >
    d
  </li>
  <li data-category="seller" class="info-item">
    e
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much @ggorlen ! And yes, previously it blinks every time I clicked on it even though I've change the value of setTimeOut function to zero.

Comment: `setTimeout` at 0 means it'll run after the whole call stack clears, so this allows a rerender to fire and repaint the screen. Then there's a moment before JS can run the callback and render a second time. I didn't mention it in the post, but I'd probably avoid this and do it all synchronously.